# Maven: TestCase ran, but test method isn't called

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-3, junit4

My tests are compiled and "run", but my test method isn't executed. Maven prints:

```
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running spring.test.Aufgabe0.TestMinimalTestCase
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@4b
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.408 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

My test class is really small and should fail:

```
package spring.test.Aufgabe0;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
public class TestMinimalTestCase {
    @Test
    public void testMinimalTest() {
        int i = 3;
        assertTrue(i == 2);
    }
}
```

I imported JUnit and configured the test path as you can see:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
...
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
```

The test suite runs in Eclipse, but I can't figure out why it's not working with maven.

### Solution:

Import testng Test. This shouldn't make a difference: "Tests in your test source directory can be any combination of the following: TestNG JUnit (3.8 or 4.x)..." [Surefire documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html)

**How do I run junit tests with testng in my scope / dependecy list?**

Comment: Why are you trying to change the default folder layout ? Where have you located your test? in `src/test/java` ?

Comment: Because my tests aren't at the default location. I'm migrating the project

Comment: Just move them to the default location and remove the appropriate configuration from your pom. will make your life easier.

Comment: this is off topic and orthogonal to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@4b
```

Looking at this I suppose you are using TestNG while Maven build, but you have import of `org.junit.Test`.

Use [`@Test`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html) from TestNG.

Comment: @StefanK. Looks like you are using TestNG

Comment: now it's working. Apparently if you also have testng in scope, maven prefers it and ignores junit tests :( Wish they did mention that in their documentation: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

Comment: @StefanK. Yes they should. Glad I could help :)